# How to make queries and send them to solr

Tags: solr

I want to make queries according to the parameters I get from my server and query solr server.

First I want a guide how to make a query url and second, how to send it to solr. For the time being I use the default graphical user interface.

Comment: Mersad, your question in it's original form was hard to understand and unlikely to fetch you any help. I edited it for clarity. Hope I didnt change the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Client Libraries provided with Solr in your application to build queries as you get from the browser and request it to solr.
These libraries provide the Solr results in the respective language objects, which are very simple to use.

[Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJava) for Java, Sunspot and rsolr with Ruby, SolrPHP for PHP and much more

Answer (score 0):

As I came to know from your other comment, you are using C#.

Here you go, **code snippet** for fetching the XML in Solr using C#

```
using System.Net; 
... 
... 

HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(solruri); 

webrequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get; 

//Get the Response from Solr 

HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse(); 

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream());
```

Variable solruri= url to Solr instance running, for example: _http://localhost:8080/solr/select......